# findById({}) in LoopBack

Tags: angular, sdk, loopback

If i want to modify this find with `findById({})`.

How to modify in loopback +angular 2 SDk?

```
.find({offset: 0,   
           limit: 100         
         })
   .subscribe(function(response: any)
      {           
       });
```

Comment: How is that related to Angular2 or SDK? What is `.find()` supposed to do? What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `findById({})` then there is no need for further filters like `offset` and `limit`, as `findById({})` return one single object based on the `id`

```
    User.findById({
      id: your_id,
      filter:{
        include:{
          relation: 'roles'
        }
      }
    })
```

This is an example of retrieving a `User` object with the `roles` relation.

Note: The syntax is based on Angular 1, haven't tried on Angular 2